# How to disable orientation on ViewController presented with UIApplication.keyWindow()

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I have a ViewController that can be presented anywhere in the app. I'm presenting it with this code `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.presentViewController`. So I want to disable orientations, only Portrait to be supported. I've tried with so many solutions, implementing `shouldAutorotate/supportedInterfaceOrientations/preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` but nothing helped. Anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your viewDidLoad?

```
viewDidLoad() {
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    shouldAutorotate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the device orientation in advance of presenting the viewController?

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

and then override the shouldAutorotate method in your "presented" viewController and return NO:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
  return NO;
}
```

or in Swift:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

and

```
override func shouldAutorotate() {
  return false
}
```

You will see the animation of the rotation, but it works in my app.